# Electron app with ngx-printer fails printing

Tags: html, angular, printing, electron

I have an Electron application where I have been working for a while. Recently I added a functionality that let's me print a ticket. It does open the window to print the ticket but sends nothing to the printer. Anyone knows whats happening? If I try this on the web application it does work and prints the ticket but I need that on electron app.
I'll paste here my code

Main.js: (I think this is where the problem resides)

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 2024,
        height: 1768,
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        resizable: true,
        backgroundColor: '#222',
        center: true,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        icon: 'produccion.ico',
        label: 'FromScratch',
        title: '',
        webPreferences: {
            nativeWindowOpen: true,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: true
        }
    })

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile('Produccion/dist/index.html')
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    mainWindow.maximize()

    // Open the DevTools.
    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

component.ts: (Only calls the button that activates the printing)

```
  imprimir(datos) {
    this.optionCode = datos['optionCode']
    this.lineaPrint = datos['Linea']
    this.referencia = datos['Referencia']
    this.orden = datos['Orden']
    this.descripcion = datos['Descripcion']
    this.cantidad = datos['Cantidad']

    /* setTimeout(() => {
      let printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
        let popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write("\n      <html>\n        <head>\n          <title>KIT</title>\n      </head>\n    <body onload=\"window.print();window.close()\">" + printContents + "</body>\n      </html>");
        popupWin.document.close();
    }, 500);
         */



    setTimeout(() => {
      this.print.nativeElement.click();
    }, 500);

  }
```

component.html: (The section im printing and the button that prints the section)

```
<div id="print-section" hidden="true" style="background-color: white;">
    <h1 style="font-size:2em">KIT - {{lineaPrint}}</h1>
    <ngx-qrcode [elementType]="elementType" [value] = "optionCode" cssClass = "aclass" errorCorrectionLevel = "L"></ngx-qrcode>
    <hr>
    <p style="font-size:2em">MODELO: {{referencia}}</p>
    <hr>
    <p style="font-size:2em">OF: {{orden}}</p>
    <hr>
    <p style="font-size:2em">{{descripcion}} - {{cantidad}} unidades</p>
</div>
<button #print hidden="true"  printTitle="report" printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

This is a picture that I get when im about to print:

[image: Example of printintg]